# Riding the Paris Metro with a kid trailer

Tags: trains, public-transport, paris

I'm going to Paris with my wife and my 3 yo daughter.
We plan to buy a [convertible bicycle/ stroller trailer](http://www.amazon.fr/Convertible-Jogger-Remorque-V%C3%A9lo-enfants/dp/B006JS46IE/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1370724910&sr=8-3&keywords=velo%20remorque).

Is it OK to ride the Metro while taking your kid along in a trailer like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything is possible. Strollers are allowed in the metro.

But I would advise against it because there are too many stairs in the Paris metro that could make your rides far from enjoyable.

If you read french, here is a blog post on the difficulties of a young mother with a stroller:  [R.A.T.P : Rame Avec Ta Poussette !](http://mapoussetteaparis.blogspot.fr/2010/03/ratp-rame-avec-ta-poussette.html) The article is relatively old, but situation has not evolved since.

Comment: I can take the stroller while my daughter goes down the stairs. But we won't be kicked out of the metro for traveling with that giant stroller?

Comment: I've seen a lot of them in the metro and I always help to carry them up the stairs.